# Почему вебсервер не воспинимает пробел %20 в ссылке?

Tags: nginx

Есть очень старый сайт со старым конфигом.

```html
map $request_uri $expires {
 default off;
 ~*\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff|svg)$ 168h;
}

map $request_uri $cacheControl {
 default no-cache;
 ~*\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff|svg)(\?v=\d+)?$ "public";
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name mysite.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.mysite.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name blog.mysite.com;
 rewrite ^(.*) https://www.mysite.com permanent;
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name media.mysite.com;
 rewrite ^(.*) https://www.mysite.com permanent;
}

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-redirects-map.txt;

server {
 listen 80;
 root /var/www/mysite/mysite/public;
 server_name www.mysite.com node1.mysite.com;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

 real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
 real_ip_recursive on;

 index index.html;

 location /search/ {
  rewrite ^/search/([^\?].*)$ https://www.mysite.com/search?search_phrase=$1 last;
 }

 location /deprecated.html {
  index deprecated.html last;
 }

 location / {
  if ($deprecated = 1) {
   rewrite ^ https://www.mysite.com/deprecated.html redirect;
  }

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 permanent;
  }
        
  if ($new_uri) {
   rewrite ^ $new_uri permanent;
  }

  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 permanent;

  add_header Cache-Control $cacheControl;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  try_files $uri @prerender;
 }

 location /api {
        root /var/www/mysite/mysite-api/web;
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        set $request_url $request_uri;
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/api/(.*)$ ) {
            set $request_url /$1;
        }

        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_url;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mysite/mysite-api/web$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/mysite/mysite-api/web;
        internal;
    }

 location /api/panel {
     root /var/www/mysite/mysite-api/web;
  try_files $uri /api/app.php$is_args$args;
 }


 error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_mysite_error.log;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_mysite_access.log;
}
```

Если сделать выборку через апи
`/api/search/locations/Hong` то данная вобрка работает.
Если сделать выборку немного другую 
`/api/search/locations/Hong%20Kong` - то ответ пустой
Хотя если руками такой же запрос выполнить к бд то записи есть.
Подскажите, что может быть загвоздка?

Comment: Потому что кто-то криво хранит данные в БД?

Comment: Хотя если руками такой же запрос выполнить к бд то записи есть.

Comment: @ivanzor А какой это такой запрос в БД. Как вы конвертируете путь к api в запрос в БД. Может для начала в том скрипте что работает с БД вывести, что он конкретно получил от веб сервера и как это обработал ? Отлаживать rewrite не видя результат его работы невозможно. Тем более что проблема может быть не в nginx, а в скрипте

Comment: @Mike 
ссылка _/api/search/locations/Hong%20Kong_
запрос к бд 
**SELECT l0_.id AS id_0, l0_.name AS name_1, l0_.latitude AS latitude_2, l0_.longitude AS longitude_3, l0_.population AS population_4, c1_.name AS name_5 FROM locations l0_ INNER JOIN countries c1_ ON (l0_.country_id = c1_.id) WHERE l0_.name LIKE 'hong kong?' ORDER BY l0_.population DESC LIMIT 5**

Comment: Решение проблемы, добавил мар
map $request_uri $request_url {
    default      $request_uri;
    ~^/api(?<1>/.*) $1;
}
И закомментировал set
  set $request_url $request_uri;
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/api/(.*)$ ) {
            set $request_url /$1;

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы, добавил мар map $request_uri $request_url { default $request_uri; ~^/api(?<1>/.*) $1; } И закомментировал set set $request_url $request_uri; if ($request_uri ~ ^/api/(.*)$ ) { set $request_url /$1;